# How to use pm2 start app.js

Tags: javascript, pm2

I am using PM2 to run the node.js server even when I close the terminal.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3HoI.png)

Even if I wait in this state, the figure below can not be seen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaI8r.png)

What is the problem?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Available from nodejs version 4.5.0 or later